# How do you select from a date range as the data source

Tags: sql, postgresql

Short of creating a table with all of the values of a date range, how would I select from a datarange as a datasource.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to create a running total of all items created within the same week from separate tables, while showing weeks with 0 new

example table:

```
items
-----------------------------
created_on | name     | type 
-----------------------------
2012-01-01 | Cards    | 1
2012-01-09 | Red Pen  | 2
2012-01-31 | Pencil   | 2
2012-02-01 | Blue Pen | 2

types
--------------
name     | id 
--------------
Fun      | 1
Writing  | 2
```

sample output:

```
----------------------------
year | week | fun | writing 
----------------------------
2012 | 1    | 1   | 0
2012 | 2    | 0   | 1
2012 | 3    | 0   | 0
2012 | 4    | 0   | 0
2012 | 5    | 0   | 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a number series for the week numbers

```
SELECT
  w.week
FROM
  (SELECT generate_series(1,52) as week) as w
```

Example

```
SELECT
  w.year,
  w.week,
  COUNT(i1) as fun,
  COUNT(i2) as writing
FROM (SELECT 2012 as year, generate_series(1,6) as week) as w
LEFT JOIN items i1 ON i1.type = 1 AND w.week = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM i1.created_on)
LEFT JOIN items i2 ON i2.type = 2 AND w.week = EXTRACT(WEEK FROM i2.created_on)
GROUP BY 
  w.year,
  w.week
ORDER BY
  w.year,
  w.week
```

Comment: Check out [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com), it's useful for testing queries against multiple types of RDBMS.

Comment: Nope — your JOIN is too restrictive.  What you have now moots `generate_series()`.  (Of lesser importance, `i.EXTRACT` prompts a syntax error and COUNT(*a boolean expression*) won't do what you want.)

Comment: Thanks for the sqlfiddle tip, the query had more than a few errors in it. It should work better now, although Postgresql doesn't consider 2012-01-01 to be part of week 1.

Answer (score 0):

Very close erikxiv, but you got me in the right direction. I have multiple tables I need to grab information from, this the additional select in the select fields.

```
select 
    date_year.num,
    date_week.num,
    (   select count(*) from items x
        and EXTRACT(YEAR FROM x.created_on) = date_year.num
        and EXTRACT(WEEK FROM x.created_on) = date_week.num
    ) as item_count
from
    (SELECT generate_series(2011, date_part('year', CURRENT_DATE)::INTEGER) as num) as date_year,
    (SELECT generate_series(1,52) as num) as date_week
where
    (
        date_year.num < EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
        OR 
        (
            date_year.num = EXTRACT (YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE) AND
            date_week.num <= EXTRACT (WEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE)
        )
    )
```